# Replace pivot operation for use in lazy evaluation with polars

Tags: python, lazy-evaluation, python-polars

I have a set of events at timestamps, and for each timestamp I need the sum of the "last" values of each username. This can be done with a pivot table, but I would like to use `LazyFrame`, because with many unique usernames, the pivot table would overflow RAM. However, `LazyFrame` does not support `pivot`.

The number of unique usernames are on the order ~1000s, with the events being in the order of 10s of millions.

### A working example with `pivot` and `DataFrame`:

The input dataframe:

```
timestamp   username    kudos
i64 str i64
1690886106  "ABC"   123
1690886107  "DEF"   10
1690886110  "DEF"   12
1690886210  "GIH"   0
```

I can achieve the task using `pivot`:

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": [1690886106, 1690886107, 1690886110, 1690886210],
        "username": ["ABC", "DEF", "DEF", "GIH"],
        "kudos": [123, 10, 12, 0],
    },
    schema={"timestamp": pl.Int64, "username": pl.Utf8, "kudos": pl.Int64},
)

result = (
    df.pivot(
        index="timestamp",
        columns="username",
        values=["kudos"],
        aggregate_function="last",
    )
    .select(pl.all().forward_fill())
    .fill_null(strategy="zero")
    .select(pl.col("timestamp"), pl.sum_horizontal(df["username"].unique().to_list()))
)
```

The results are correct:

```
shape: (4, 2)
timestamp   sum
i64 i64
1690886106  123
1690886107  133
1690886110  135
1690886210  135
```

How would one implement this with `LazyFrame` such that it is efficient for a large number of unique usernames (i.e. using lazy evaluation and possibly without a giant sparse pivot table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case your pivot is basically doing two jobs, one is like a groupby and the other is to create all the unique combinations of timestamp and username. We can do that without pivot.

First we create the unique combinations and join it back to the original like this...

```
(df
 .select(pl.col('timestamp','username').unique().implode())
 .explode('timestamp')
 .explode('username')
 .join(df, on=['timestamp','username'], how='left'))
shape: (12, 3)
┌────────────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp  ┆ username ┆ kudos │
│ ---        ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ 1690886106 ┆ DEF      ┆ null  │
│ 1690886106 ┆ GIH      ┆ null  │
│ 1690886106 ┆ ABC      ┆ 123   │
│ 1690886107 ┆ DEF      ┆ 10    │
│ …          ┆ …        ┆ …     │
│ 1690886110 ┆ ABC      ┆ null  │
│ 1690886210 ┆ DEF      ┆ null  │
│ 1690886210 ┆ GIH      ┆ 0     │
│ 1690886210 ┆ ABC      ┆ null  │
└────────────┴──────────┴───────┘
```

The rest of the operations looks pretty similar to what you're doing after the pivot the only extra nuance is going to be the use of a window function on the `forward_fill.fill_null` step.

Putting it all together you have...

```
df=df.lazy()
(df
 .select(pl.col('timestamp','username').unique().implode())
 .explode('timestamp')
 .explode('username')
 .join(df, on=['timestamp','username'], how='left')
 .with_columns(pl.col('kudos').forward_fill().fill_null(0).over('username'))
 .groupby('timestamp',maintain_order=True)
 .agg(pl.col('kudos').sum())
 .collect())
shape: (4, 2)
┌────────────┬───────┐
│ timestamp  ┆ kudos │
│ ---        ┆ ---   │
│ i64        ┆ i64   │
╞════════════╪═══════╡
│ 1690886106 ┆ 123   │
│ 1690886107 ┆ 133   │
│ 1690886110 ┆ 135   │
│ 1690886210 ┆ 135   │
└────────────┴───────┘
```

This should be significantly faster than a pivot with rowwise sums as neither of those are particularly well optimized.

**Update for bigger data**

If the dataset has few unique combos of timestamp and username then the scale of the above will be bad as it'll make a df that's too big.

Alternatively, we can mimic the behavior of pivot using a generator with `when.then`

I'm getting errors trying to use the new `sum_horizontal` so we also need an efficient way to do a rowwise sum.

Starting with...

```
df = pl.DataFrame({ 
"timestamp": np.arange(1, 1e6+1), 
"username": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e6)), 
"kudos": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e6)), }, 
schema={"timestamp": pl.Int64, 
"username": pl.Utf8, 
"kudos": pl.Int64}, )
```

We want to create a series of all the unique usernames which we'll use a couple times

`usernames=df.get_column('username').unique()`

then convert the df to lazy

`df=df.lazy()`

Now we create an expression for a rowwise sum of all our usernames we have to use the internal `__add__` method:

```
rowwise=pl.col(usernames[0]).__add__(pl.col(usernames[1]))
for username in usernames[2:]:
    rowwise=rowwise.__add__(pl.col(username))
```

I tried chaining it like `rowwise=rowwise+pl.col(username)` but it creates a huge nest of parenthesis like `(a+(b+(c+(d+e(.....))))` and that makes it die at a future step

Then we do:

```
result=(df
 .select(
    ['timestamp'] +
    [(pl.when(pl.col('username')==x).then(pl.col('kudos'))).alias(x) for x in usernames]
)
 .with_columns(pl.col(usernames).forward_fill().fill_null(0))
 .select('timestamp', rowwise.alias('sum'))
 .collect()
 )
```

where the first `select` mimics the pivot then the next `with_columns` does the same forward/fill as before. The last select just implements the rowwise summation.

My jupyter cell can do that in 6.9s in contrast to the pivot method of closer to 9s

If the timestamp field has duplicates you'll need to do something like

```
result.groupby('timestamp', maintain_order=True).agg(pl.col('sum').last())
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to scale well and runs forever? For example on this larger dataframe:
```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "timestamp": np.arange(1, 1e6+1),
        "username": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e6)),
        "kudos": np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=int(1e6)),
    },
    schema={"timestamp": pl.Int64, "username": pl.Utf8, "kudos": pl.Int64},
)
```

Comment: Are you saying the pivot method handles that well and this one doesn't?

Comment: Yes, the pivot method takes 10 seconds with 1000 random usernames and 1 million timestamps. The explode/join method does not seem to finish and just keeps running. (However, the pivot method does not scale to larger number of usernames, due to RAM, for example 5000 random usernames crashes.)

Comment: hmm that's an interesting one. The exploded/imploded all combos thing results in 1e6 * 1000 rows. Is it the case in real data that the timestamp only appears once?

Comment: The combination of (timestamp, username) appears once. At the same timestamp, multiple usernames can be updated.

Comment: I put in an edit that should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you, however this still explodes in RAM causing the kernel to crash once you go to thousands of usernames, e.g. 5000 usernames. I agree that it is slightly faster, but the main point is to go beyond what the pivot table can achieve. Sorry for being annoying. For reference, a plain `for` loop with `iter_rows` using a `dict` that stores the last value for each username takes about a minute for 5000 usernames and 1e6 rows, so it should be possible?